# Select query to get a single record from stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, rdlc

I am developing a Billing website where on filling the bill I receive an option to print it.I am using MVC architecture but the print function is placed on a separate webform.Facing a problem about how to print the bill of a single customer from database.Right now I am getting the rdlc print report for all the customers present in the database. Please help me in the the query section in the webform to select a particular customer through his customer ID.

My controller code :-

```
public ActionResult Print()
    {

        int Id = 3; //Customer ID taken as example
        Response.Redirect(@"~/print.aspx?id=" + Id);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

My webform code :-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int Id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            PopulateReport(Id);
        }
    }

    private void PopulateReport(int ID)
    {
        using (MISContext db = new MISContext())
        {

            var v = (from a in db.GetOrderDetails()
                     select a);
            ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("dsBooking", v.ToList());
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rd);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

User [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Tbl_Customer customer= (from u in db.Tbl_Customer.Where(u => u.Id == ID) select u).FirstOrDefault();
```